# Why do the RSS feeds created by Views not validate?

Tags: 7, feeds

Using the W3C Feed validator my very basic RSS feed from a View fails validation. It seems to be all of the additional attributes in the  element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <rss version="2.0" xml:base="http://mydomain.com/blog" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" og="http://ogp.me/ns#" rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#" sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#" skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
    <channel>
    ...
```

I get this error: "Unexpected xsd attribute on rss element" with this help info: http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/error/UnexpectedAttribute.html

The feed loads fine in my RSS reader app on my iPhone though :s

Comment: That is nothing to do with views, and everything to do with the RDFa module

Comment: Ok, then why does the RDFa module not create an RSS feed that validates :p